# Django view requests for a specific time period from database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am developing a project with Django. I want to display the requests from the database in a certain time interval, for example `datetime.now()` - I want to display the requests 2 minutes ago. Is there a filtering code you can suggest for this?

```
class Bonusrequest(models.Model): 
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Username') 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Name") 
    choise = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Choise') 
    result = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Result') 
    created = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Date") 
    descrpt = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Description")
```

Comment: `somedatetime__lte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)`? If this is not enough, can you share your models?

Comment: Can you put it i n your post and not here in the comments

Comment: As long as the post request comes, such a model is created and the database is saved. My goal is to view the post requests that came 2 minutes ago.

Comment: added on question

Comment: Ok in that case you can use `created` (assuming you have `auto_now_add=True`): `created__lte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)`

Comment: This will get all `Bonusrequest` that was created in the past two minutes

Comment: That's not exactly what I wanted to ask. Here's how I can tell you what I want to do.

When the user makes a post request, I get the IP address before sending the data to that user. If there is no other request from that IP address in the last 2 minutes, I show the data to the user. I do not want to show the data if the request has been sent from the same IP within the last 2 minutes.